# FancyBox close from within iframe and take parent page to the link

Tags: jquery, fancybox, href, location-href

I found applying the following function to a links `onclose`  works to close Fancybox from within an iFrame:
`parent.$.fancybox.close();`

I want to take this further and have the link take the parent page to a new url.
I've tried the following but it doesn't work:

```
<a onclick="location.href='http://www.domain.com/page/';parent.$.fancybox.close();"> Close and go to page</a>
```

using `a href` doesn't work either as the `onclose` takes precedence.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Very simple solution... can't believe I didn't think of this!!!

```
<a href="http://www.domain.com/page/" target="_parent"> Close and go to page</a>
```

Sometime, I swear I try to make things more difficult than they actually are!

Comment: Man, I don't care this is just a "thank you" reply.
Be well and thank you. Clean and quick solution.

Answer (score 17):

You can also do this by writing a function on the parent page:

```
function closeFancyboxAndRedirectToUrl(url){
    $.fancybox.close();
    window.location = url;
}
```

Then on the link within the iframe, you can do this:

```
<a onclick="parent.closeFancyboxAndRedirectToUrl('http://www.domain.com/page/');">Close and go to page</a>
```

Comment: This is also quite useful if you want to use a function in the modal that calls a function in the parent to actually close it (extremely useful for showing notifications within the parent when the modal closes, e.g after submitting a form)

Answer (score 17):

no need to close fancy box just use

```
function name(){
    self.parent.location.href='pageg.php';
}
```

Comment: I've tried all the suggestions above and only this one worked for me!
Thank you!